# WSG84, GPS, GEOID and other altitudes

Tags: gps, elevation, wgs84, cesium, altitude

**INTRO**

A bit of tool introduction, but the problem is not related to this directly.

I have an app in [CesiumJS](https://cesium.com/cesiumjs/).

I am using [Cesium World Terrain](https://cesium.com/blog/2018/03/01/introducing-cesium-world-terrain/), and get altitude using [Sample Terrain Most Detailed](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/sampleTerrainMostDetailed.html)

This would allow me to `As is typical of the Cartographic type, the supplied height is a height above the reference ellipsoid (such as Ellipsoid.WGS84)` So getting an height in WGS84.

**PROBLEM**

I have my WGS84, but I am using a server that require an altitude in MSL, not WGS84. Which require me to convert my WGS84 altitude to MSL.

Over the internet I found that a way would be

```
MSL = GPS - GEOID
```

I then took some measure using those sites :

- [Geoid Height Calculator](https://www.unavco.org/software/geodetic-utilities/geoid-height-calculator/geoid-height-calculator.html) ;
- [Find Altitude on Map](https://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-google-maps-find-altitude.htm); and
- my Cesium app.

And found the following difference (in meter)

```
GPS   |  CESIUM       | GEOID      |  DIFF (GPS / CESIUM)

669   | 705           | 49.421     | +36
52    | 88            | 37.162     | +36
51    | 36            | -15.992    | -15
0     | -86           | -98        | +86
```

From what I understood, GPS and WSG84 should be the same, so my GPS and my Cesium altitude should be the same...

But it turn out that, if I use the previous formula I do find the correct value for GPS, but not with my Cesium WSG84 value.

**QUESTION**

When referring to altitude, are WGS84 and GPS measure identical, or is GPS just based on WGS84 but require additional conversion to retrieve a WSG84 altitude ?

Comment: Interesting question - if you can edit your questions down to one (and I'd suggest rephrasing it a bit) this is really worthwhile.

Comment: Also have a look at other discussions on [ellipsoid](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157005/meaning-of-elevation-above-surface-of-ellipsoid/157006#157006) and [GPS error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225850/how-big-is-the-error-of-relative-elevation-between-two-points-taken-from-gps-rel).